# cmake find_path not working for simple file

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to find a problem why cmake is not able to find a custom openssl version, therefore I debugged the original findOpenssl.cmake.

There they search for the ssl.h file. So, I created a small cmake file which tries to find out the issue:

```
project(CMAKETEST)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH "/home/user/Documents/CMakeTest/openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h")
message(STATUS CUSTOMOPENSSLPATH: ${OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH})

find_path(TEST123
    NAMES ${OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH}
)

message(STATUS ${TEST123})
```

I created an empty ssl.h file in the above folder, but cmake is not able to find the file. TEST123 is always NOT-FOUND.

### Solution:

```
set(OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH "/home/user/Documents/CMakeTest/openssl/include/openssl")
find_path(TEST123 NAMES ssl.h PATHS "${OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH}")
```

## Update

This more concrete example does not work as expected:

```
project(CMAKETEST)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

set(OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH "/home/user/Documents/CMakeTest/openssl/")
find_path(TEST123
    NAMES openssl/ssl.h HINTS "${OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH}"
    PATH_SUFFIX include
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

message(STATUS ${TEST123})
```

when removing `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` then it finds the system openssl library in /usr/include

## Update 2

https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenSSL.cmake#L195-L204

```
find_path(OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR
  NAMES
    openssl/ssl.h
  ${_OPENSSL_ROOT_HINTS_AND_PATHS}
  HINTS
    ${_OPENSSL_INCLUDEDIR}
    ${_OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  PATH_SUFFIXES
    include
)
```

finds first the path in /usr/include, if I add `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` it finds it. Probably it was because some caching that it was not found during I wrote this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't working because you use it incorrectly, for your case it should be like this:

```
set(OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH "/home/user/Documents/CMakeTest/openssl/include/openssl")
find_path(TEST123 NAMES ssl.h PATHS "${OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH}")
```

Or simply `find_path(TEST123 ssl.h PATHS "${OPENSSL_CUSTOM_PATH}")`

---

In your update you have a error `PATH_SUFFIX` should be `PATH_SUFFIXES`.

Comment: Thank you @ixSci thank you! I added a more concrete example which does not work

Comment: @Murmi updated the answer but note that I'm not debugging with you. So please stick to your question and don't update it with the new code.